# What exactly is written to disk with an LVM basic install on 1T drive?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mac, lvm, gpt

I need to reverse an LVM install to an Intel MAC 1T disk, if possible.  Even if it's not possible, I still want to know what exactly is written to the disk after pvcreate, vgcreate and lvcreate are done in an automated Ubuntu Install (14.04.4).  From what I can see, the drive was repartitioned with a GPT and a hybrid MBR.  I can reverse that, I think.  What I'm most interested is what is the size and location of the LVM file system Master File Table and other meta-data structures that are written to the new partitions (3).  I don't believe anything was written to the new swap(?) partition -- right?  If someone knows the byte or 512 block quantity and location of the lvm vg lv MFT, etc. meta-data structures, it would be terrific!  Thanks.

Comment: No, you can not simply undo formatting the disk and installing Ubuntu.  It is time to restore from backup.

Comment: I have no indications, nor is it likely that the disk was formatted. The disk was repartitioned and lvm setup on it.  I want to know exactly what the lvm setup software does to the disk to set it up.

Comment: It's also possible that nothing was done to the disk except repartitioning, and the identifier of the partition only indicates 'lvm partition'.  I need an answer from someone who knows the details.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer with the following reservations: (1) The LVM install was only the initial setup and no files were written to the LVM system, (2) The intel-MAC OS X 10.10.5 1TB drive was restored to apparent perfect filesystem order after reversing the LVM rewrite of the MBR-GPT.  Apple's Disk Utility said the system was all ok, except for some notable minor aberration with the 'partition map' that it corrected (I reviewed the MBR-GPT and found nothing different than what I restored.) (3) The beginning of 2 of the new LVM partitions fell near where damage should have occurred if, for example, a 
file system Master File Table was written to disk. (4) There were archive files from vgcreate and lvcreate, but I decided not to use them because an internal look disclosed text meta-data for the programs and not binary data.
Here are the backup/archive files:

```
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo vgcfgrestore -l ubuntu-studio-vg

  File:     /etc/lvm/archive/ubuntu-studio-vg_00000-1891332443.vg
VG name:        ubuntu-studio-vg
Description:    Created *before* executing 'vgcreate ubuntu-studio-vg /dev/sda3'
Backup Time:    Mon Mar 21 08:54:25 2016

  File:     /etc/lvm/archive/ubuntu-studio-vg_00001-1577468959.vg
VG name:        ubuntu-studio-vg
Description:    Created *before* executing 'lvcreate -l 236242 -n root ubuntu-studio-vg'
Backup Time:    Mon Mar 21 08:54:27 2016

  File:     /etc/lvm/archive/ubuntu-studio-vg_00002-1979915262.vg
VG name:        ubuntu-studio-vg
Description:    Created *before* executing 'lvcreate -l 2032 -n swap_1 ubuntu-studio-vg'
Backup Time:    Mon Mar 21 08:54:28 2016

  File:     /etc/lvm/backup/ubuntu-studio-vg
VG name:        ubuntu-studio-vg
Description:    Created *after* executing 'lvcreate -l 2032 -n swap_1 ubuntu-studio-vg'
Backup Time:    Mon Mar 21 08:54:28 2016
```

My first thought was that the archives were binary files of the sectors overwritten, and the backup is the lvm data structure, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  The documentation isn't clear at all about such archive and backup files.

The partitions made by Ubuntu install LVM are as follows (1TB drive, 512 byte sectors, 1 MiB partition boundaries) via gdisk command-p:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   8300  
   2         1050624         1550335   244.0 MiB   8300  
   3         1550336      1953523711   930.8 GiB   8E00
```

The codes are from gdisk version 0.8.8, 8300 = Linux filesystem, 8E00 = Linux LVM.

For comparison:
The MAC had 4 KiB partition boundaries, Protective MBR, Standard GPT, see
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2166/_index.html (2006)
for very useful information that doesn't seem to completely apply to my ex-wife's MAC: EFI had 'boot' attribute and apparently used.  No free space between 'Customer' and 'Recovery HD'.  Note, Wikipedia 'GPT partition' correlated gdisk 'Apple boot' as also 'Recovery HD', and apparently it is correct, because Apple's Disk Utility said specifically that 'Partition map' and 'Recovery HD' were in good order.  Here is the MACs partitions as shown by gdisk command-p.  The names are standard names of gdisk, but they can be changed after setting the code (GUID)(if important):

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System
   2          409640      1952255591   930.7 GiB   AF00  Apple HFS/HFS+
   3      1952255592      1953525127   619.9 MiB   AB00  Apple boot
```

```
Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-3): 1
Partition GUID code: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B (EFI System)
Partition unique GUID: 90381538-1853-482F-AC87-F0D020A7F166
First sector: 40 (at 20.0 KiB)
Last sector: 409639 (at 200.0 MiB)
Partition size: 409600 sectors (200.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000004
Partition name: 'EFI system partition'

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-3): 2
Partition GUID code: 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple HFS/HFS+)
Partition unique GUID: 62AE0BBA-6C11-423E-89DC-C855437BF0F7
First sector: 409640 (at 200.0 MiB)
Last sector: 1952255591 (at 930.9 GiB)
Partition size: 1951845952 sectors (930.7 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Customer'

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-3): 3
Partition GUID code: 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple boot)
Partition unique GUID: 9F160AE6-1D09-4A25-BD09-D622A94B48F9
First sector: 1952255592 (at 930.9 GiB)
Last sector: 1953525127 (at 931.5 GiB)
Partition size: 1269536 sectors (619.9 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Recovery HD'
```

But, apparently, nothing more than the rewriting of the MBR-GPT was done. Ubuntu 14.04.4 LVM install just put GUIDs for Linux filesystem and Linux LVM.  It is notable that the MBR (Master Boot Record) was rewritten into a hybrid MBR instead of the standard Protective MBR, but it's not clear why this was done -- something that Ubuntu needs or thinks might be needed/useful on this 2013 intel MAC (Spain).

My explanation of LVMs lack of writing to disk is that LVM uses just LBA information without any formatting writing to disk, and perhaps only writes meta-data to disk when it writes data to disk (in this case, it never did).  Maybe somebody can explain this. What are the half GiB and quarter GiB partitions used for?

This information will be useful if you mistakenly enter the LVM install and don't have or want to do a full 1TB restore from backup.  The first half of /var/log/partman will give you all you need to rebuild the MBR-GPT with GPT-fdisk (named gdisk).  It's a great tool with an author with a mischievous sense of humor.

I should say a few words about using gdisk, but this isn't the place.)
It's best to practice with a new tool before doing serious work.

Good luck and good cheer to all.